# Как получить информация о сеансах работы с БД, в которых есть незакрытые транзакции?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Как из представлений словаря данных получить информацию обо всех сеансах работы с БД, в которых есть незакрытые транзакции?

Насколько я понимаю, нужно обращаться к `v$session` и `v$transaction` и делать выборку `v$session.sid` и `v$session.username`.

Например, через консоль и SQL*Plus в виде двух колонок - ID сеанса и имя пользователя.

Для определения незакрытых транзакций можно ли использовать ограничение `v$transaction.flag=7811`?

Например, так:

```
SELECT v$session.sid, v$session.username
FROM v$session, v$transaction
WHERE v$transaction.flag=7811;
```

---

Версия: Oracle Database 11g Release 2

Comment: А с чём у вас сложности возникли? Соедините две таблицы и выводите.

Comment: Вот здесь "в которых есть незакрытые транзакции" сложности, т.е. как мне ввести подобное ограничение?

Comment: "v$transaction.flag=7811" - зачем он вам?

Comment: Мне показалось, что так можно указать, что транзакция не закрыта..

Comment: Нет, флаг  значит совсем другое.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
select s.sid, s.serial#, s.username
from v$transaction t
inner join v$session s on t.addr = s.taddr
;
```

> no rows selected

```
select 1 from t1 for update;

select s.sid, s.serial#, s.username
from v$transaction t
inner join v$session s on t.addr = s.taddr
;

       SID    SERIAL# USERNAME 
---------- ---------- ----------
        34      55338 OE
```

Следует учесть, что "незакрытые транзакции" не означает, что произошли изменения данных. В примере выше, например, запрос с `for update` ничего не изменил.

Comment: Хорошо, думаю, что понял вас. Попробую данный вариант. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 6):

@0xdb уже показал вам как посмотреть все транзакции. Иногда бывает полезным найти только тех пользователей и их сессии, которые блокируют какие либо объекты БД (таблицы, индексы и т.д.):

```
set lines 200 pages 200
col inst_id for 99
col obj for a45
col lock_mode for a16
col blocker_sid_serial_sqlid for a45
col os_user_pid for a18
col machine for a30
break on blocker_sid_serial_sqlid skip page
select   l.inst_id as inst_id
    ,o.owner||'.'||o.object_name as obj
    ,case l.locked_mode
        when  0     then '0:none'
        when  1     then '1:null (NULL)'
        when  2     then '2:row-S (SS)'
        when  3     then '3:row-X (SX)'
        when  4     then '4:share (S)'
        when  5     then '5:S/Row-X (SSX)'
        when  6     then '6:exclusive (X)'
        else        to_char(l.locked_mode)
     end as lock_mode
    ,l.oracle_username||' ('||s.sid||','||s.serial#||') ['||s.sql_id||']' as blocker_sid_serial_sqlid
    ,l.os_user_name||' ['||l.process||']' as os_user_pid
    ,s.machine
from gv$locked_object l
join dba_objects o
  on l.object_id = o.object_id
join gv$session s
  on (s.sid = l.session_id and s.inst_id=l.inst_id)
/* where o.owner like '&&OWNER.%' */
order by inst_id, blocker_sid_serial_sqlid, obj
;
```